# Relation rename for a particular part in query (oracle10g)

Tags: sql, oracle, rename

Question : find the customer name and account number from the account which has the highest balance .

My_query :

```
select customer_name 
from (
  select * 
  from depositor,
       account 
  where depositor.account_number = account.account_number **as T** 
    and balance >= (select balance from T )
);
```

Can i give a name 'T' for the part `( select....depositor.account_number = account.account_number)`?

Comment: it gives me a error!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you have a two  questions 
1) How get the customer_name with hiest blance

a) with ordering

```
select customer_name 
from (  select * 
from depositor,account 
where depositor.account_number = account.account_number 
order by balance DESC ) 
where rownum < 2 ;
```

b)

```
select max(customer_name) keep (dense_rank last order by balance nulls first)  
from depositor,account 
where depositor.account_number = account.account_number
```

2) How we may use alias in query block. You may use construction "with"

```
with t as (select * from depositor,account where depositor.account_number = account.account_number)
select customer_name from T 
where balance >= (select max(balance) from T ) ;
```